# Phatch will not load (Kubuntu 17.04)

Tags: kubuntu, kde

hopefully someone can help.

I had MintKDE installed on my laptop, and as I recall Phatch would not load - instead I just got the logo, but the program itself never started. I applied the changes detailed here - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=811184#12 - and it then worked.

I've recently changed OS to Kubuntu, and Phatch now does not load - the symptoms are the same - I get a Phatch logo, but it never actaully starts. I've removed it and reinstalled it, and tried the changes as detailed, but it still will not load.

I wonder if anyone could help? Phatch saves me a lot of time when it works!

Thanks.

---

Kubuntu 17.04
Plasma 5.9.4
KDE Framweworks 5.31.0
Kernel 4.10.0-22generic
OS Type 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and [this fix](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=811184#12) helped:

> In the file `/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/wxPil.py` I changed the
>   words `fromstring` and `tostring` to `frombytes` and `tobytes`.
>
> Now Phatch seems to work with the latest `python-imaging` and
>   `python-pil` libraries in Sid.
>
> Below is my new `/usr/share/phatch/phatch/lib/pyWx/wxPil.py`:
>
> ```
> # Copyright (C) 2007-2009 www.stani.be
> #
> # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
> # it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
> # the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
> # (at your option) any later version.
> #
> # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
> # but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
> # MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
> # GNU General Public License for more details.
> #
> # You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
> # along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/
>
> # Follows PEP8
>
> import Image
> import wx
>
>
> def pil_wxImage(image):
>     if image.mode == 'P':
>         image = image.convert('RGBA')
>     if image.mode == 'RGBA':
>         wx_image = wx.EmptyImage(*image.size)
>         wx_image.SetData(image.convert("RGB").tobytes())
>         wx_image.InitAlpha()
>         wx_image.SetAlphaData(
>             image.convert("RGBA").split()[-1].tobytes())
>     else:
>         wx_image = wx.EmptyImage(*image.size)
>         new_image = image.convert('RGB')
>         data = new_image.tobytes()
>         wx_image.SetData(data)
>     return wx_image
>
>
> def pil_wxBitmap(image):
>     return wx.BitmapFromImage(pil_wxImage(image))
>
>
> def wxImage_pil(wx_image):
>     size = wx_image.GetSize()
>     image = Image.new('RGB', size)
>     image.frombytes(wx_image.GetData())
>     if wx_image.HasAlpha():
>         alpha = Image.new('L', size)
>         wx_alpha = wx_image.GetAlphaData()
>         alpha.frombytes(wx_alpha)
>         image = image.convert('RGBA')
>         image.putalpha(alpha)
>     return image
>
>
> def wxBitmap_pil(wx_bitmap):
>     return wxImage_pil(wx.ImageFromBitmap(wx_bitmap))
> ```